# React testing lib userEvent.click not passing target text to handleClick function

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a unit test that uses `userEvent.click`. It finds the text to click on and it does call the `handleClick` function but the `Event.currentTarget.innerText` is not being passed in. It is the `userEvent.click(screen.queryByText(/adatest/));` line that fires the handler. Any ideas?

Here is the test:

```
    test("renders modal when clicking search item", () => {
      renderHeader(newState);
      const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/Search coin…/);
      userEvent.click(input);
      userEvent.type(input, "a");
      userEvent.click(screen.queryByText(/adatest/));
      expect(screen.queryByText(/coin: adatest/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

Here is the click handler:

```
    function handleClick(Event) {
    const coinCurrencyPair = Event.currentTarget.innerText + "usd";
    const markets = Object.values(usdPairsSelector);
    markets.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.pair === coinCurrencyPair && item.active === true) {
        dispatch(increment());
        const coinObj = { exchange: item.exchange, coinPair: coinCurrencyPair };
        dispatch(fetchCoin(coinObj));
      }
    });
    setCoinText(Event.currentTarget.innerText);
    const chartInputObj = unixStartAndEndTimes23And24(
      Event.currentTarget.innerText,
      new Date()
    );
    const startDate = convertDateToUnix(new Date());
    console.log("date: ", new Date());
    console.log("unix: ", startDate);
    // dispatch(fetchModifiableChartData(chartInputObj));
    setOpen(false);
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setCoinSymbol("");
    setOpenModal(true);
  }
```

My `coinCurrencyPair` const should hold `adatestusd`, but it is `undefinedusd`

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer you are looking for, but another approach could be to mock the event and use the `fireEvent.click` instead of `userEvent.click`

ex:

```
const event = { currentTarget: { innerText: "adatest" } }

fireEvent.click(screen.queryByText(/adatest/), event)
```